# Deploying Windows 8.1 store apps on Windows 10

Tags: deployment, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1, windows-10, sideloading

I'm sideloading Windows 8.1 app on Windows 10. I know Win 8.1 apps required a sideloading key when it deploy through Windows 8.1 OS but due to the new feature on Windows 10 "Sideload apps" does that sideloading key still required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. It's not required.

According [this article](http://www.howtogeek.com/219651/windows-10-allows-you-to-sideload-universal-apps-just-like-android-does/)

> With Windows 8, Microsoft copied Apple’s iPad and iPhone model,
>   forcing you to get your apps from Microsoft’s curated store. Windows
>   10 shifts back to a more PC-like, Android model — you can get apps
>   from anywhere you like.

According [technet.microsoft.com](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/deploy/sideload-apps-in-windows-10)

> In Windows 10, sideloading is different than in earlier versions of
>   Windows:
>
> ```
> You can unlock a device for sideloading using an enterprise policy, or through Settings
> License keys are not required
> Devices do not have to be joined to a domain
> ```